# Ethernet RJ45 Connector?

Tags: connector, ethernet, rj45

I have plenty of HR911130A in stock because they are small and directly compatible with Raspberry PI.

For another project, the reference design recommends the 7498010210A connector, which is slightly different.

Would it be ok to use the HR911130A instead of the 7498010210A?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It depends on what is the device/chip and what it requires from the magjack.

Comment: I am using a DP83822IRHBR PHY

Comment: It should work at a pinch. However if you're designing a commercial product you'd want to do tests to verify the performance.

Comment: @Kartman What should I do with P5..P9. Tie them to ground?

Comment: probably short them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which is slightly different.

slightly?

Well, the first one (2 pairs) is for 10/100 Base-T a.k.a. Fast Ethernet while the other one (4 pairs) is for 1000 Base-T a.k.a. Gigabit Ethernet.

> ... the reference design recommends the 7498010210A connector

100 Base-T hardware and signalling can be used with 1000 Base-T. So yes, you can use your existing 4 pair magjack with your 10/100 Base-T application.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite: the LED pin-out is different. Though, it's possible that only the numbering scheme is different, even though the same physical pins are used in both connectors.

Regardless, we can't tell for sure without looking at the PCB layout.